# What is the current browser support for the w3c `FileWriter` interface?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, standards

What is the current browser support for the w3c `FileWriter` interface?

I'm mainly interested in Chrome and Firefox for desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem). Only supported in Chrome with the webkit prefix.

Comment: uhm, i already stepped into that page, but is not specifying `FileWriter` separately. i have Chrome with those versions and `FileWriter` is not there

Comment: @danza Used the webkit prefix? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/